# pgcrypto: unable to normal user

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12, pgcrypto

I need to enable `pgcrypto` on a postgresql 12 instance.

I enabled the extension and checked it was ok:

```
postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;
CREATE EXTENSION
postgres=# SELECT digest('blah', 'sha256');
                               digest
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 \x8b7df143d91c716ecfa5fc1730022f6b421b05cedee8fd52b1fc65a96030ad52
(1 row)
```

I followed recommandations I read on SO:

```
postgres=# GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION digest(bytea,text) TO normaluser;
GRANT
postgres=# GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION digest(text,text) TO normaluser;
GRANT
```

Sadly, still no way to use that function with a "normaluser".

```
normaluser@planck:5432/cryptodb> SELECT digest('blah', 'sha256');
ERROR:  42883: function digest(unknown, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT digest('blah', 'sha256');
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
LOCATION:  ParseFuncOrColumn, parse_func.c:631
Time: 52,065 ms
```

Any hint is welcome, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the question, you can see I'm connected as superuser `postgres` when I create the extension and *not* into the database `cryptodb` used be user `normaluser`.
So I connect to database `cryptodb` with `postgres` and now `normaluser` can use the pgcrypto function `digest` in `cryptodb` context.

TL;DR; : *Connect to the correct database before `CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;`*